# How do I find the current location of the cursor in a text box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, keypress

I'm using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411557/jquery-keypress-event-get-text/1411608#1411608):

```
$("input[x]").keypress(function (e) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    //process the single character or
    var textValue = $("input[x]").val();
    var fulltext = textValue + c;
    //process the full text
});
```

A comment noted that this assumes the cursor is at the end of the text box. I tried searching how to get the location of the cursor for solution of this issue, but could not figure out how to do it?

How does one find the current location of the cursor?

Comment: you can try e.pageX or e.clientX.

Comment: @TusharGupta - I researched more on this and found out that we can accomplish this using JQuery JCaret plugin. Please refer to the webpage below for more details

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret

Comment: This is not a forum, the title is supposed to be a question! Flagged for deletion.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, questions are generally expected to be self-contained. Your question was previously phrased as a direct reply to a previous answerer. While it's good that you're asking it as a new question rather than in a comment or answer as some others mistakenly do, you should try to make your question to be less like an appeal to a previous author and more like a genuinely new question, even if you cite the code from a previous answer. I've edited your question a little to hopefully make it a little more self-contained; feel free to change it if I've misinterpreted it.

Comment: Also, if you've figured out the answer to your question, by all means, go ahead and post it as an answer rather than adding it as a comment. If you add it as a real answer, you can get credit for it if anyone else finds it useful.

Comment: Sorry for the mess here. This happened as I am new to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched more on this and found out that we can accomplish this using JQuery JCaret plugin. 
Please refer to the webpage below for more details about the plugin and its usage: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret